# ¿Como hacer que entity framework devuelva solo el objeto consultado?

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla de colonias y devolviendolas en un API en formato JSON

```
colonias = (from c in conn.Colonias
                        where c.CodigoPostal.Codigo == cp
                        && (bool)c.AuActivo
                        select c).ToList();
return colonias;
```

si me esta devolviendo las colonias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que me esta incluyendo las relaciones que EF esta obteniendo de esos registros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debo crear objetos con los resultados que incluya solo la información que necesito? o alguien conoce un método mas limpio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer dos cosas utilizar un ViewModel y utilizar AutoMapper para mapear solo las propiedades que quieres que se muestren o haciendo una proyección y así solo consultar las propiedades que quieres (las demás vendrán null).

```
colonias = (from c in conn.Colonias
                        where c.CodigoPostal.Codigo == cp
                        && (bool)c.AuActivo
                        select new Colonia{
                            //props que quieres consultar
                        }).ToList();
return colonias;
```

Comment: si, solo retorne un objeto con os atributos que ocupaba